# Adding numerous checkboxes to mySQL table

Tags: php, mysql, checkbox

I am currently creating a form with checkboxes in it. At the minute i have it working that it is only adding the last selected checkbox to the database table. I need it to add all the selected values to the table. I think i may need to use implode but i am unsure where to put it. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

***actionplan.php***

```
<h1>My Action Plan</h1>

<?php
if (isset($_GET['success']) && empty($_GET['success'])) {

} else {
if (empty($_POST) === false && empty($errors) === true) {
$actionplan = array(
    'studentid'             => $user_data['studentid'],
    'interests_hobbies'     => $_POST['interests_hobbies'],
);
actionplan($actionplan);
header ('Location: actionplan.php');
exit();

} else if(empty($errors) === false){
echo output_errors($errors);
}
?>

 <form action="" method="post">

    <li>
    <p class="p4">
        What are your interests and hobbies?*
    <center>
    <table border="0">

 <tr>
 <td><p class="p6"><input type="checkbox" name="interests_hobbies" value="Animal Care"/>Animal Care</td>
 <td><p class="p6"><input type="checkbox" name="interests_hobbies" value="Computer Games"/>Computer Games </td>
<td><p class="p6"><input type="checkbox" name="interests_hobbies" value="Gardening"/>Gardening</td>
<td><p class="p6"><input type="checkbox" name="interests_hobbies" value="Internet Browsing"/>Internet Browsing</td>
<td><p class="p6"><input type="checkbox" name="interests_hobbies" value="Sculpting"/>Sculpting</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><p class="p6"><input type="checkbox" name="interests_hobbies" value="Bird Watching "/>Bird Watching</td>
  <td><p class="p6"><input type="checkbox" name="interests_hobbies" value="Fishing"/>Fishing</td>
<td><p class="p6"><input type="checkbox" name="interests_hobbies" value="Golfing"/>Golfing </td>
  <td><p class="p6"><input type="checkbox" name="interests_hobbies" value="Painting"/>Painting </td>
<td><p class="p6"><input type="checkbox" name="interests_hobbies" value="Social Networking"/>Social Networking</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><p class="p6"><input type="checkbox" name="interests_hobbies" value="Bowling"/>Bowling</td>
 <td><p class="p6"><input type="checkbox" name="interests_hobbies" value="Food Tasting"/>Food Tasting </td>
<td><p class="p6"><input type="checkbox" name="interests_hobbies" value="Gymnastics"/>Gymnastics </td>
 <td><p class="p6"><input type="checkbox" name="interests_hobbies" value="Reading"/>Reading </td>
<td><p class="p6"><input type="checkbox" name="interests_hobbies" value="Watching Movies"/>Watching Movies</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><p class="p6"><input type="checkbox" name="interests_hobbies" value="Camping"/>Camping</td>
<td><p class="p6"><input type="checkbox" name="interests_hobbies" value="Football"/>Football </td>
<td><p class="p6"><input type="checkbox" name="interests_hobbies" value="Interior Design"/>Interior Design </td>
<td><p class="p6"><input type="checkbox" name="interests_hobbies" value="Surfing"/>Surfing </td>
<td><p class="p6"><input type="checkbox" name="interests_hobbies" value="Yoga"/>Yoga</td>
</tr>
</table>    

    <li>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </li>

 </ul>

 </form>
```

***users.php***

```
function actionplan($actionplan) {
array_walk($actionplan, 'array_sanitize');

 $fields = '`' . implode('`, `', array_keys($actionplan)) . '`';
 $data = '\'' . implode('\', \'', $actionplan) . '\'';

mysql_query("INSERT INTO `actionplan` ($fields) VALUES ($data)");
}
```

Comment: No. you don't use explode. you use a php extension and name your checkboxes `interests_hobbies[]` which then gives you an array of checkboxes when the form's processed by php. then you put each checkbox into its OWN record in the db, instead of this csv business.

Comment: Each checkbox should have an unique `name`. If only one option is allowed, use `input type="radio"`.

Comment: Do you mean like?

 <td><p class="p6"><input type="checkbox" name="animalcare" value="Animal Care"/>Animal Care</td>
 <td><p class="p6"><input type="checkbox" name="computergames" value="Computer Games"/>Computer Games </td>

When i use braces nothing gets added to the table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to include braces in PHP:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="interests_hobbies[]"...
```

This will give you an array in $_POST `$_POST['interests_hobbies']`. Remember that you only get a POST value if the checkbox is checked. So you could potentially have a null value for $_POST['interests_hobbies'] if no checkboxes are checked, so make sure your code handles that.

**Update:**
If user.php is the script handling your POST, then your form action needs to be:

```
<form action="users.php" method="post">
```

Then at the top of users.php, add this code to dump the POST to the screen:

```
echo "<pre>";var_dump($_POST['interests_hobbies']);echo "</pre>"
```

(You don't need the  tags, but I like them when I use var_dump inside HTML.)

Once you have verified that you are getting the right POST values, you can proceed from there to output or store the values.

Comment: When i include braces i also dont get anything outputting?

Comment: I would use var_dump to check the value of the POST at the top of your script. I would set the form action to the same script name rather than blank just to be explicit.

Comment: You also have some strange HTML - not sure it this is all the code though - but for instance you have a <li> without an opening <ul> tag.

Comment: No sorry, this isnt all the code. There was just too much code to paste in. The tags are all opened and closed correctly. where would you advise using var_dump revent?

Comment: Somewhere at the top inside your body tag. echo "<pre>";var_dump($_POST['interests_hobbies']);echo "</pre>";

Comment: Once you have confirmed that your are getting the correct values in the POST, then you can start following the trail in your code to where it's supposed to output.

Comment: I thought i had it but its just doing the same thing, when i put in the braces the field changes to blank and when i take out the braces only the last selected checkbox is being added to the table?